# Magento 2 - how to redirect to popup login form while add a product to wishlist

Tags: magento2, wishlist

I add a popup login form in my magento 2 template and when I add a product to the wishlist and I'm not logged in, I want to show the popup for the login and then add to wishlist the product.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use code:

1. code html:

you can looking at **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml**

2. add in your layout

   ```
   <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
       <block class="\Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="mlx_guestwishlist2_js" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml"/>
   </referenceContainer>
   ```
3. add styles

.block-customer-login{display: none;}

4. add js

```
jQuery('.towishlist')
    .removeAttr('data-post')
    .click(function(){
        jQuery('.block-customer-login').show();
    });
```

Comment: Hello, As I am using magento 2 can you please elaborate that in which file we need to make changes or shall we create a different module to open pop-up on wish list button.